# Problem with two vector equations which is perpendicular to each other

Tags: vectors

I am tackling a vector problem as shown below:

```
A line L1 has equation r=(-5,-3,2)+λ(-1,2,2)
A line L2 passing though the origin intersects L1, and is perpendicular to L1
```

> Then here is the questions: (A)Find a vector equation of L2
>   (B)Deermine the shortest distance from the origin to L1

I don’t know how to find L2...the only thing I know is the dot product of L1 and L2 is equal to zero.Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The equation of line $L_2$ is:
$$
(0,0,0)+k(u,v,w) \ .
$$

**Edit:** The $(0,0,0)$ is because the line $L_2$ goes through the origin. The generic vector $(u,v,w)$ is one that is orthogonal to the vector of $L_1$.

**Edit 2:** Since $L_1$ and $L_2$ are perpendicular, then the dot product of their vectors must be zero:
$$
(u,v,w) \cdot (1, -1/2, -1/2) = 0 \ .
$$

**Edit 3:** So, we have one equation on $u$, $v$ and $w$.
You can obtain 3 more equations because $L_1$ and $L_2$ have to intercept themselves, one equation for the $x$ coordinate, another for $y$ and another for $z$. However, we have 5 unknowns: $\lambda$, $k$, $u$, $v$ and $w$.
You'll find that you could choose either $u=1$ or $v=1$ or $w=1$ (choose one of those only). Now you have 4 equations with 4 unknowns.

Comment: Hmm...So the vector equation is (0,0,0)+λ(-1,-1/2,-1/2)?

Comment: Please explain more clearly, thanks!!!

Comment: I added more information. Now is your turn to work on this exercise. :)

Comment: Thank you, my problem is, I think if two lines are perpendicular, the product of their gradient should be -1, therefore I came up with the equation(0,0,0)+λ(1,-1/2,-1/2). But then I found that the product of their direction vector is not equal to 0. Where did I get my answer wrong?

Comment: I gave you 1 equation for $u$, $v$ and $w$. Can you obtain more equations to solve your problem? What other information is helpful for this problem?

Comment: Thank you for your 2nd editing, but if (u,v,w)*(1,-1/2,-1/2)=0, there still needs two other equations to find the three values...Or can I just assumes any (u,v,w) which apply to the o product equation??

Comment: The thing is, I cannot find more equations to solve the problem.....

Comment: I edited in more info. Can you solve it from this point onward?

Comment: Understood!! Thank you so much !!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you think it's appropriate, you can accept my answer (there is a green button on the top left of it).